# Получить только процессы отображающиеся на панели задач

Tags: c#, windows, процесс

Сейчас использую такой способ получения всех процессов:

```
Process[] processes = GetAllProcesses();
```

Каким образом можно получить только те процессы, которые отображаются на панели задач?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Насколько я вижу, эти [процессы](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process?view=netframework-4.7.2) можно получить отфильтровав из вашего списка те, которые имеют MainWindowHandle больше нуля:

```
Process[] processes = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcesses();
var apps = processes.Where(x => x.MainWindowHandle != IntPtr.Zero);
```

В принципе, тот же результат можно получить проверив Handle != null но вы можете получить ошибку об отсутствии прав, если запускаете из-под учётки без админских прав.

Пока запускал обратил внимание. Нотификации аутлук (всплывают на панели задач) почему-то не отображаются в списке задач, хотя визуально видны хоть и на таскбаре. Вам подобные нотификации нужны?

Comment: Кстати, а правильно ли говорить "больше нуля" в контексте InPtr? С точки зрения ссылок а-ля С++ вроде как некорректно, с точки зрения того, что это специальный int для объединения int32 и int64 вроде как можно.

Comment: Большинство мусора отсеивается, но `ScriptedSandbox64` и `ShellExperienceHost` как были, так и остались, однако в диспетчере они помечены как "фоновые". Добавить их в исключения не проблема, но что делать, если у юзера есть другой мусор?

Comment: @Виталий У меня таких процессов нет, но попробуйте отфильтровать ещё процессы с пустым MainWindowTitle -- вероятно, у таких фоновых процессов он будет пустым.